# Adding additional rows of missing combination in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column-D which has value of other column names [Col A, COl B , COL C] , i want to add additional rows of missing combination. My dataframe looks like below:
[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn0Ks.png)

```
import pandas as pd
data={'colA':[0,0,0],'ColB':[0,0,0] ,'ColC':[0,0,0],'ColD':['ColA','ColA','ColB'],'Target':[1,1,1]}
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
```

I need resulting df as:

```py
data={'colA':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],'ColB':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ,'ColC':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],'ColD':['ColA','ColB','ColC','ColA','ColB','ColC','ColB','ColA','ColC'],'Target':[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]} 
df=pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df)
```

[Resulting Data needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOhyW.png)

Comment: unable to reproduce a resulting df due to `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Please check the updated question now ,added image for reference @politicalscientist

Comment: your example doesn't show rules you are trying to achieve...  It would be better if you used 1-6 in ColA and ColB to then show how that translates into your resultant data frame.

Comment: The value of column-A,B,C is irrelevant here . I just need remaining combination of values for each row with resulting target as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Given contents of ColA,B,C are irrelevant and you just want to repeat values in ColD and Target it just becomes a `dict` comprehension right.   Nothing to do with `pandas`

```
data={'colA':[0,0,0],'ColB':[0,0,0] ,'ColC':[0,0,0],'ColD':['ColA','ColA','ColB'],'Target':[1,1,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

pd.DataFrame({k:v*3 
              if k not in ["Target","ColD"] 
              else [1,0,0]*3 
              if k=="Target" else ["ColA","ColB", "ColC"]*3 
              for k,v in data.items()})
```